# how to solve "no such plot" error while plotting in netlogo?

Tags: netlogo

I am new to netlogo and facing the following error while plotting the mean of properties associated with patches:

no such plot: " patch 0 0"
error while patch 0 0 running SET-CURRENT-PLOT
  called by procedure GO
  called by Button 'go'

But patch 0 0 clearly exists and is predefined in the code as follows:

```
'globals [ k ] ; interaction constant
patches-own [ a b c d' e' ] ; state variables of properties
                       ; a is the Proportion and variety of Blend of land use
                       ; b is the Land uses with supportiveness for complimentary  activities
                       ; c is the Vehicular and Pedestrian Intensity
                       ; d is the Intensity of Nodes in urban web
                       ; e' is the Frequency of Enforced Vigilance
to setup
  clear-all
  set k initial-k
  setup-patches
  reset-ticks
end
to setup-patches
  ask patches [ set pcolor yellow ] ; defines the patches as built up in an area

  ; to define road patches (horizontal)
  ask patches [ if pycor = 0 [ set pcolor grey ] ]
  ask patches [ if pxcor = 0 [ set pcolor grey ] ]
  ask patches [if pycor = 9 [ set pcolor grey ] ]
  ask patches [ if (pycor = 6) and (pxcor < -4 )[ set pcolor grey ] ]
  ask patches [ if (pycor = 3) and (pxcor < -4 ) [ set pcolor grey ] ]
  ask patches [ if (pycor = 4) and (pxcor > 3 ) [ set pcolor grey ] ]
  ask patches [ if (pycor = -6) and (pxcor > 7 ) [ set pcolor grey ] ]

  ; to define road patches (vertical)
  ask patches [ if (pycor > 0) and (pxcor = -10 ) [ set pcolor grey ] ]
  ask patches [ if (pycor > 0) and (pxcor = -5 ) [ set pcolor grey ] ]
  ask patches [ if (pycor < 0) and (pxcor = -7 ) [ set pcolor grey ] ]
  ask patches [ if (pycor < 0) and (pxcor = -3 ) [ set pcolor grey ] ]
  ask patches [ if (pycor < -3) and (pxcor = 4 ) [ set pcolor grey ] ]
  ask patches [ if (pycor > 3) and (pxcor = 4 ) [ set pcolor grey ] ]
  ask patches [ if (pycor > 0) and (pxcor = 7 ) [ set pcolor grey ] ]

  ; to define nodes as patches
  ask patches [ if pxcor = 0 and pycor = 0 [ set pcolor red ] ]
  ask patches [ if pxcor = 7 and pycor = 0 [ set pcolor red ] ]
  ask patches [ if pxcor = -3 and pycor = 0 [ set pcolor red ] ]
  ask patches [ if pxcor = -5 and pycor = 0 [ set pcolor red ] ]
  ask patches [ if pxcor = -7 and pycor = 0 [ set pcolor red ] ]
  ask patches [ if pxcor = -10 and pycor = 0 [ set pcolor red ] ]
  ask patches [ if pxcor = 4 and pycor = 4 [ set pcolor red ] ]
  ask patches [ if pxcor = 7 and pycor = 4 [ set pcolor red ] ]
  ask patches [ if pxcor = 7 and pycor = 9 [ set pcolor red ] ]
  ask patches [ if pxcor = 4 and pycor = 9 [ set pcolor red ] ]
  ask patches [ if pxcor = 0 and pycor = 9 [ set pcolor red ] ]
  ask patches [ if pxcor = -5 and pycor = 9 [ set pcolor red ] ]
  ask patches [ if pxcor = -10 and pycor = 9 [ set pcolor red ] ]
  ask patches [ if pxcor = -10 and pycor = 6 [ set pcolor red ] ]
  ask patches [ if pxcor = -10 and pycor = 3 [ set pcolor red ] ]
  ask patches [ if pxcor = -5 and pycor = 6 [ set pcolor red ] ]
  ask patches [ if pxcor = -5 and pycor = 3 [ set pcolor red ] ]

  ; to set intial values of properties for patches
  ask patches with [pcolor = yellow] [ set a random-float 0.9] ; initial a
  ask patches with [pcolor = yellow] [ set b random-float 0.9] ; initial b
  ask patches with [pcolor = grey] [ set c random-float 0.9] ; initial c
  ask patches with [pcolor = red] [ set d' random-float 0.9] ; initial d'
  ask patches with [pcolor = grey] [ set e' random-float 0.9] ; initial e'
end
to go
  tick
  if ticks >= 52 [ stop ]
  ask patches with [pcolor = yellow]
  [
    let fc [c] of one-of patches with [pcolor = grey] ; reports c of any one 
grey patch of neighbours
    let fe' [e'] of one-of patches with [pcolor = grey] ; reports e' of any one grey patch of neighbours
    let fd' [d'] of one-of patches with [pcolor = red] ; reports d' of any one red patch of neighbours
    if a < 0.1 [ set a 0.1
    if a > 0.9 [ set a 0.9 ] ]
    if b < 0.9 [ set b b + (k * a) + (k * fc) + (k * fd')
    if b > 0.9 [ set b 0.9 ] ]
    if b > 0.1 [ set b b - (k * fe')
    if b < 0.1 [ set b 0.1 ] ]
  ]

  ask patch 0 0
  [ let fa [a] of one-of patches with [pcolor = yellow]
    let fb [b] of one-of patches with [pcolor = yellow]
    let fc [c] of one-of patches with [pcolor = grey]
    let fe' [e'] of one-of patches with [pcolor = grey]
    let eeep (fa + fb + fc + d' + 1 / fe') / 5
    let deep (1 / fa + 1 / fb + 1 / fc + 1 / d' + fe') / 5
    output-print eeep
    output-print deep
    set-current-plot " patch 0 0"
    set-current-plot-pen "eeep"
    plot eeep
    set-current-plot-pen "deep"
    plot deep
  ]
end'
```

I have been trying to solve this for quite sometime and will be grateful for any help.
Thank you!

Comment: Have you included a plot with the appropriate name on the interface? It's not telling you there's no patch, it's telling you there's no plot. I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve by referring to a patch as a plot name. Also, I would recommend that NetLogo beginners place all the plot code in the plot dialogue, not in the code tab. So you simply do something like `plot mean [eeep] of patches` as the pen.

Comment: Yes the plot in the interface is with the same name and I also tried writing the plot code in the plot dialogue but the problem is still occurring. Thanks anyway for replying... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The patch named  `patch 0 0` exists. However, that does not mean that the plot named  " patch 0 0" exists. You have simply mistyped the name of the plot (perhaps you have the incorrect number of spaces).

I suggest you rename your plot to something that doesn't look like a patch identifier to reduce confusion. Try something like "plot-0-0", renaming both on the interface in the plot dialogue, and also in the code.

Comment: Okay I'll try that. Thank you.. :)